# bootstrap modal popup button does not have onclick serverside event

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

my web page has a view result button which is a toggle for bootstrap modal popup.
I am unable to create a onclick event for it as control does not go to server side when I click it, only a popup is displayed. How can I get the onclick event to raise serverside event handler.
As you can see I tried creating OnClick event handler but with no success.

```
<p class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnshowmodal" onclick="Save_Result" runat="server">View Result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the 'button' to 'asp:Button` because this is an asp.net control that triggers events on code behind.

```
<asp:Button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnshowmodal" onclick="Save_Result" runat="server" Text="View Result"></asp:Button>
```

left the other attributes as they are - just set the Text. Will be render not a button but an input, but your job will be done.